# Jquery returns undefined when trying to pull an element by its id with onmousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, onmousedown

i have a javascript function that is going to change the text of the element in the font tag when i click it. I am trying to get the element by its id tag with jquery but when i console.log the jquery result it comes up as undefined.
the all allWordsList variable is comming from python flask and i have confirmed that javascript is indeed receiving it properly
the problem seems to be with this line `var wordID = $(el).attr("id");` because it returns undefined when i console.log it

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function changeText(el){
        var allWordsList = JSON.parse({{listFontsJ|tojson|safe}});
        console.log(allWordsList);
        var wordID = $(el).attr("id");
        console.log(wordID);
        var display = document.getElementById(wordID);
        display.innerHTML = '';
        display.innerHTML = allWordsList[wordID]["english"];

    }
  

</script>
```

`<font id="1" size = '10' color = "red" onmousedown= "changeText()"> hello </font>`

Comment: FYI: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your code is using elements and attributes that are either deprecated (like `font`), no longer needed (like `type=text/javascript`) or legacy and not standard (like `onmouseover`).

[You should not be using HTML event attributes like `onXyz`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991) and instead be separating your HTML from your JavaScript and do your event binding in JavaScript. And then, if the event handler is executing as a result of interacting with a DOM element, you can just use `this` to refer to the element that triggered the event.

Also, it makes no sense to clear the `innerHTML` of the element and then on the very next line to set it. Just set it. But, really, you should [avoid `.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) when you can (which is almost always) because it has security and performance implications. And you're not even setting the text to any HTML anyway. Instead, use [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

[And, the `font` tag is deprecated.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) You should be setting the size and color of text with CSS and wrapping your text in valid elements, like `div` or `span`.

Lastly, while and `id` that starts with a number is valid in HTML5, CSS won't recognize those `id`s. It's better to give your elements an `id` that starts with a letter and is meaningful. If you need a number to be associated with the element, it's better to use a [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Here are all of those suggestions put together:

```css
#item1 { font-size:20px; color:red; }
```

```html
<div id="item1" data-index="1"> hello </div>

<script>
    let allWordsList  = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul" ];

    document.getElementById("item1").addEventListener("mousedown", changeText);

    function changeText(){
       // Set the text to the data-index value of the HTML element:
       this.textContent = allWordsList[this.dataset.index];
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i tried what you said but the problem is definitely with var wordID = $(el).attr("id"); because if i set var wordID = 1 then it works

Comment: @Mattytripps See my updated answer with working code. The problem was that you were using an inline HTML event attribute, when you should be doing event binding in JavaScript.

Comment: the only problem with the solution that you gave me above is that im generating the html with a for loop in python so i cant have the id = item1 because i dont think that i can generate a bunch of #item1 #item2 #item3 tags in css. Each word needs to be colored differently and displayed on the same line as if it is one p tag rather than individual words

Comment: im sending this to javascript ```<font id="0" data-index="0" color = "red" onmousedown="changeText()">Я</font><font id="1" data-index="1" color = "black"></font><font size='12' color='blue'> </font><font id="4" data-index="4" color = "red" onmousedown="changeText()">хочу</font>``` each word needs its own id

Comment: this definately helped me. though im not quite out of the woods yet. but my code has substantially improved because of your input. Could you take a look at this question that I posted here, if you have a chance?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66191845/javascript-on-click-change-the-html-of-an-element-different-than-the-one-that-w